# Version of IIS & .net framework

Tags: iis-7.5, .net-framework-version

Is there any IIS version release after IIS 7.5?
And is there any update for .NetFramework released after .NetFramework 4?

Comment: To my knowledge, the latest IIS Version is 7.5 and the latest .NET Framework (at least production) is .NET 4.0. Maybe there are service packs for .NET 4.0 but not a new release. Check Microsoft's website.

Comment: There is a minor update available on .Net 4.0. Check out : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS is considered part of the operating system, so probably IIS vNext will only come when Microsoft releases its next version of Windows, which may not happen in the coming months. But once Microsoft provides public betas of it, you can test it out.

.NET 4 is still the latest, and like @Pawan pointed out, there are updates for .NET already, but SP1 is not yet announced.